# How to setup External Public Url for ReactiveOAuth2 client in Spring Java with kubernetes env

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

In my Spring boot Java-based Application, I have written my custom Oauth2 web client for third-party system to automatically get access token upon any API call. The code works fine when i deployed it on my Local development setup with Eureka enabled however the same doesn't work with my remote Azure env where discovery is Kubernetes.

```
@Configuration("customOAuthWebClientConfiguration")
public class CustomOAuthWebClientConfiguration {


    @Bean("customWebClient")
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder,
        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager) {

        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2ClientFilter =
            new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager);
        oauth2ClientFilter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("custom");
        oauth2ClientFilter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("custom");

        return webClientBuilder.filter(oauth2ClientFilter).build();
    }

    /**
     * ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.
     */
    @Bean
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
        ObjectProvider<ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider> reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider,
        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository reactiveClientRegistrationRepository) {

        InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService = new
            InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(reactiveClientRegistrationRepository);

        AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager clientManager =
            new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                reactiveClientRegistrationRepository, clientService);
        //if available this will be the load balanced client provider.
        reactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider
            .ifAvailable(clientManager::setAuthorizedClientProvider);

        return clientManager;
    }


    @Bean
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository reactiveClientRegistrationRepository(ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(
            List.of(clientRegistration));
    }

}
```

This is how my application.yaml looks like

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          custom:
            token-uri: https://external/oauth/token/
        registration:
          custom:
            authorizationGrantType: client_credentials
            clientId: ${clientId}
            clientSecret: ${clientSecret}
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      discovery:
        enabled: true
    loadbalancer:
      enabled: true
    discovery:
      client:
        simple:
          instances:
            external:
              - uri: ${public-host}
```

The problem is when I deploy my spring application on Kubernetes, it tries to find a k8 service with the name external. However, the same config works fine(i.e. simple discovery) with Eureka. Can you please guide how to set up an external public URL for the Oauth2 web client with Kubernetes discovery?